# Internal error /lib/upowerd on Ubuntu 15.10. What is causing this error?

Tags: error-handling

Every time I start Ubuntu 15.10 I get this error:

```
Internal error:
ExecutablePath: /usr/lib/upower/upowerd
Package: upower 0.99.3-1build2
ProblemType: crash
```

I read on [some forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2256436) that this may be caused by connecting an idevice (such as an iPhone). What is causing it? Does anyone else have the same problem?

A possible suggested fix is to install the library "libimobiledevice-utils" but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I saw this question in searching for a solution for a upowerd crash when trying to connect my iPhone 5s to Ubuntu 15.10, installed the 'libimobiledevice-utils' package, and was able to connect the phone with no further crashes.

Comment: This does not work for me. Hopefully someone can figure out another solution for those of us still having the same problem.